# Why async / await allows for implicit conversion from a List to IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I've just been playing around with async/await and found out something interesting. Take a look at the examples below:

```
// 1) ok - obvious
public Task<IEnumerable<DoctorDto>> GetAll()
{
    IEnumerable<DoctorDto> doctors = new List<DoctorDto>
    {
        new DoctorDto()
    };

    return Task.FromResult(doctors);
}

// 2) ok - obvious
public async Task<IEnumerable<DoctorDto>> GetAll()
{
    IEnumerable<DoctorDto> doctors = new List<DoctorDto>
    {
        new DoctorDto()
    };

    return await Task.FromResult(doctors);
}

// 3) ok - not so obvious
public async Task<IEnumerable<DoctorDto>> GetAll()
{
    List<DoctorDto> doctors = new List<DoctorDto>
    {
        new DoctorDto()
    };

    return await Task.FromResult(doctors);
}

// 4) !! failed to build !!
public Task<IEnumerable<DoctorDto>> GetAll()
{
    List<DoctorDto> doctors = new List<DoctorDto>
    {
        new DoctorDto()
    };

    return Task.FromResult(doctors);
}
```

Consider cases 3 and 4. The only difference is that 3 uses async/await keywords. 3 builds fine, however 4 gives an error about implicit conversion of a List to IEnumerable:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 
'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<EstomedRegistration.Business.ApiCommunication.DoctorDto>>' to 
'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<EstomedRegistration.Business.ApiCommunication.DoctorDto>>'
```

What is it that async/await keywords change here?

Comment: What's the difference between 1 and 4? Am I blind and not seeing it?

Comment: based on the question (athe compiler output) I think that 4 in real code has `List<DoctorDto> doctors = new ...` am I right? ... yep

Comment: @CarstenKönig You are right - corrected it

Comment: @Hammerstein My fault it should have been List instead of IEnumerable, I've just corrected it.

Comment: the answer now is rather obvious: the compiler will insert a implicit cast where the `await` is - you see the same behaviour if you are using LINQ. Maybe someone can have a look a the C# specs for await and link them - for some reason I cannot find them right now

Comment: @CarstenKönig That reason it the interesting part :)

Comment: @gisek The reason really is quite simple - `await` unwraps the value from the `Task<List<DoctorDto>>`, so it gets `List<DoctorDto>`. The `return` in an `async` method then wraps this back into a task - but since it's supposed to return `Task<IEnumerable<DoctorDto>>` rather than `Task<List<DoctorDto>>`, it will do an explicit cast. You can't cast `Task<List<DoctorDto>>` to `Task<IEnumerable<DoctorDto>>`, but you *can* cast `List<DoctorDto>` to `IEnumerable<DoctorDto>>` - so all you need is cast the payload. `return await` handles that for you.

Comment: why not just typecast #4?
`return Task.FromResult(IEnumerable<DoctorDto>doctors);`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`Task<T>` is simply not a covariant type.

Although `List<T>` can be converted to `IEnumerable<T>`, `Task<List<T>>` cannot be converted to `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`. And In #4, `Task.FromResult(doctors)` returns `Task<List<DoctorDto>>`.

In #3, we have:

```
return await Task.FromResult(doctors)
```

Which is the same as:

```
return await Task.FromResult<List<DoctorDto>>(doctors)
```

Which is the same as:

```
List<DoctorDto> result = await Task.FromResult<List<DoctorDto>>(doctors);
return result;
```

This works because `List<DoctorDto>` can be converted `IEnumerable<DoctorDto>`.

Comment: But the thing is that if you add async/await keywords it suddenly can be converted.

Comment: This obviously explains why the 4th example fails, but the question is actually about why the 3rd example *passes*. An explanation about the async/await generated code is required.

Comment: @avo It doesn't actually have anything to do with co-variance at this point, `List<DoctorDto>` simply implements `IEnumerable<DoctorDto>` so can be supplied as such.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, I agree, although the main idea and the code of my explanation remains correct.

Comment: @avo Indeed, I just wanted to remove the talk about variance, it's confusing enough when used in the correct place ;-)

Comment: You can always just explicitly specify the return type of FromResult, which then eliminates the rather useless 'return await', which you'd want to avoid if performance is a priority.

Answer (score 18):

Just think about your types. `Task<T>` is not variant, so it's not convertible to `Task<U>`, even if `T : U`.

However, if `t` is `Task<T>`, then the type of `await t` is `T`, and `T` can be converted to `U` if `T : U`.

Answer (score 7):

Clearly you understand why `List<T>` can  at least be returned as `IEnumerable<T>`: simply because it implements that interface.

Also clearly, the 3rd example is doing something "extra" that the forth one isn't. As others have said, the 4th fails because of the lack of co-variance (or contra-, I can never remember which way they go!), because you are directly trying to offer an instance of  `Task<List<DoctorDto>>` as an instance of `Task<IEnumerable<DoctorDto>>`.

The reason the 3rd passes is because `await` adds a big bunch of "backing code" to get it to work as intended. This code resolves the `Task<T>` into `T`, such that `return await Task<something>` will return the type closed in the generic `Task<T>`, in this case `something`.

That the method signature then returns `Task<T>` and it *works* is again solved by the compiler, which requires `Task<T>`, `Task`, or `void` for async methods and simply massages your `T` back into a `Task<T>` as part of all the background generated asyn/await continuation gubbins.

It is this added step of getting a `T` from `await` and needing to translate it *back* into a `Task<T>` that gives it the space it needs to work. You are not trying to take an existing instance of a `Task<U>` to satisfy a `Task<T>`, you are instead creating a brand new `Task<T>`, giving it a `U : T`, and on construction the implicit cast occurs as you would expect (in exactly the same way as you expect `IEnumerable<T> myVar = new List<T>();` to work).

Blame / thank the compiler, I often do ;-)